# Joining two columns from one table to one column in other returning different or the same result for each of the 2 columns

Tags: mysql, join, unions, aliases

I have 4 tables that I can join easily. The last join requires two columns to be joined to a categories table; which, I want a different value (categoryName) returned in the same row.

## Output desired

customerID, adID, categoryselectedID, offeredcategoryID, categoryID, categoryName (this one is correct), wantedcategoryID, categoryID, categoryName (this one displays the same name as the offeredcategoryID)

## Tables and columns

1. customers:           customerID (PK)
2. ads:                 adID (PK), customerID (FK)
3. categoriesselected:  categoryselectedID (PK), adID (FK), offeredcategoryID (FK), wantedcategoryID (FK)
4. categories:          categoryID (PK), categoryName

(mysql returns 7 records and all info except categoryName is the same for both offering and wanting)

```
SELECT customers.*, ads.*, categoriesselected.categoryselectedID, categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID, offeredcategory.categoryID, offeredcategory.categoryName, categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID, wantedcategory.categoryID, wantedcategory.categoryName

FROM customers
    INNER JOIN ads ON ads.customerId = customers.customerID
    INNER JOIN categoriesselected ON categoriesselected.adID = ads.adID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS offeredcategory ON offeredcategory.categoryID = categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS wantedcategory ON wantedcategory.categoryID = categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID
```

(I've also tried a UNION and UNION all both return 14 records 7 for offering the 7 for wanting the categories as opposed to being only 7 records with different categoryName on same row.)

```
SELECT customers.*, ads.*, categoriesselected.categoryselectedID, categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID, categories.categoryID, categories.categoryName,  'Offered Category' AS Category 
FROM customers
    JOIN ads ON ads.customerId = customers.customerID
    JOIN categoriesselected ON categoriesselected.adID = ads.adID 
    JOIN categories ON categories.categoryID = categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID

UNION ALL

SELECT customers.*, ads.*, categoriesselected.categoryselectedID, categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID, categories.categoryID, categories.categoryName,  'Wanted Category' AS Category 
FROM customers
    JOIN ads ON ads.customerId = customers.customerID
    JOIN categoriesselected ON categoriesselected.adID = ads.adID 
    JOIN categories ON categories.categoryID = categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you rephrase what your problem is? And please modify your table information format, it is hard to read.

Comment: See changes please

Comment: Well the second query would indeed yield 14 row(s) because you explicitly stated that all records for the first query under the `Category` column be `Offered Category` whilst in the second query, the `Category` would be `Wanted Category`.

Comment: If you could plot sample data, as well as the current output versus the expected output, then I would gladly help you with your queries.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the problem lies on the last join, which is giving you an incorrect output.

```
SELECT customers.*, ads.*, categoriesselected.categoryselectedID, 
    categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID, offeredcategory.categoryID, offeredcategory.categoryName, 
    categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID, wantedcategory.categoryID, wantedcategory.categoryName
FROM customers
    INNER JOIN ads ON ads.customerId = customers.customerID
    INNER JOIN categoriesselected ON categoriesselected.adID = ads.adID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS offeredcategory ON offeredcategory.categoryID = categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS wantedcategory ON wantedcategory.categoryID = categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID
```

Note that I changed the join query condition from `offeredcategoryID` to `wantedcategoryID` for `wantedcategory`